# MVC - Request Class

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I have been trying to figure out if the request object should handle sorting out the controller and action or if that should be left up to the router?  What I mean is that when the request object is passed to the router, if it should already contain the properties for the controller and action.  Forgive me if this has been answered before but I couldn't find anything specific to this topic.

Most of the content I have found on this doesn't even use a request object.  I know I could download a framework and look but I figure it might be just as easy to ask here.

Comment: If your gonna down vote can you at least provide a link to show material on this subject?

Comment: Do you know what [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) is?

Comment: Agreed: Downvoting without explanations or tips is bad. Especially when a question is not pure crap. And this one is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very different in many Frameworks, but the basics are similar to this:

The Request Object (or any other kind of container for the passed input data) should only have this one responsibility: Containing the input (and sometimes result) data.

A specific other object (Called "Front Controller" in many frameworks) should sort out what controller and action to be called and nothing else.

This logic usually continues with the actuall called controller that only has the responsibility of selecting the correct model, and the model of only handling the data. Some frameworks split this even further.
But the theory is allways same: Each part of your app should only have to focus on one single task.

The link from @teresko above tells you the theory behind this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle

Comment: Thank your for the elaboration.  I'm new to the whole mvc concept so this really helps.

Comment: tbh, MVC is just one overly hyped pattern. There are many others and MVC often doesnt even make sense for a PHP backend. But I will likely get much heat for an opinion like that ;)

Comment: @ToBe , you answer actually isn't entirely true. In PHP the *Front Controller* doesn't need to be a class (it's actually better it isn't). Instead it can be a simply linear script file. Also, it is kinda ambiguous: what you meant with "results" that `Request` instance contains? Did you mean the parsed input?

Comment: I was giving examples on how most frameworks do it. Of course you can do it however you want. Most frameworks I know of do it this way. With result data, I meant the computed data from your model that is than passed some view.

Comment: In that case -1, because `Request` instance should not be accumulating data from model layer for passing it to the view. Hell, the views should be requesting data from model layer, if you are actually implementing anything even remotely resembling an MVC architecture.

Comment: Like I said, I am not telling you how to do MVC. I'm am telling you how some Frameworks do it. Whatever. I was actually strengthening your point. But wth...